# SELECT different row IF no rows returned

Tags: mysql

This is kind of hard to headline, but given this statement:

```
SELECT DISCOUNT FROM people_discounts WHERE ID = ? AND PGROUP = ?
```

Let's assume I enter ID 5 and PGROUP 2. This row does not exist in the table (`fetch` returns false in the case of PHP and mysqli). In that case I want the row that would have been presented had the statement been:

```
SELECT DISCOUNT FROM people_discounts WHERE ID = ? AND PGROUP = 0
```

With ID still being 5, but PGROUP "fallen back" to 0 instead, which let's assume **always exists**.

Is this possible with some kind of IF, CASE or maybe some other keyword that I'm not aware of?

I know this can of course be accomplished by running a second statement in the case of no rows, but that's not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

presuming the query should only ever return a single row

```
select discount from people_discount
where id = ? and (pgroup = ? or pgroup = 0)
order by pgroup desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Jesus. How could I not think of that. Maybe it's time to sleep. Edit: I also had an INNER JOIN in my headline. What.

Answer (score 1):

If `limit` seems "impure" you could use other tricks.

This might be more portable though it assumes that discount is never negative:

```
select abs(max(case when proup <> 0 then discount else -discount end))
from people_discount
where id = ? and pgroup in (?, 0)
group by id
```

Not every platform has a top/limit/fetch option. And some people object to non-set-based queries. I'm simply offering a hack of sorts with those people in mind or at least as an exercise in thinking about problems in a different way.

The idea is just to assume there cannot be a negative discount and to use that end of the number scale to temporarily "store" the fallback discount for pgroup 0. `MAX()` accomplishes the equivalent of sorting and limiting by favoring the positive value when both are present. `ABS()` restores the sign of the result.

Comment: I actually don't know what this does. Limit does answer my question perfectly. The fact that it doesn't solve my problem at all is another thing entirely. I should have gone to sleep instead of asking, although it seems the question intrigues somebody. Edit: I appreciate the effort though. Just that I was considering deleting it which now seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Based on the information in your question this is a completely valid answer. I have no doubt that the `limit` option is more useful to you though.

Comment: I meant I was considering deleting the question - I'm sure your answer is good :)